# Replace SNMP "Timeout: No Response from <IP_Address>" with Specific Text

Tags: linux, snmp

I have a script that queries OID details via SNMPWalk, the problem is when the certain IP (example is 172.20.36.8) is not reachable, it displays `Timeout: No Response from 172.20.36.8`. Is there a code that could replace that response from snmp query so that if it displays like that, I would like to appear the word "Idle" instead of that "Timeout:..."

here is the part of the script that I am running:

```
for EACH in `echo $APIP`
  do
    SectorID=`$SNMPWALK -v2c -c Canopy ${EACH} ${SNMPOID}.1.1.16 | awk '{print $4}'
    ActiveSubs=`$SNMPWALK -v2c -c Canopy ${EACH} ${SNMPOID}.1.7.1 | awk '{print $4}'
    UniqueSubs=`$SNMPWALK -v2c -c Canopy ${EACH} ${SNMPOID}.1.7.18 | awk '{print $4}'
    printf "%s\t| %s\t| %s\t| %s\t|\n" "${EACH}" "${SectorID}" "${ActiveSubs}" "${UniqueSubs}"
  done
```

Now here is the result of the said part of script

```
172.20.36.3     |   1   |      2        |      4        |
172.20.36.4     |   2   |      5        |      8        |
172.20.36.5     |   3   |      11       |      16       |
Timeout: No Response from 172.20.36.6
Timeout: No Response from 172.20.36.6
Timeout: No Response from 172.20.36.6
172.20.36.6     |       |               |      0        |
172.20.36.7     |   5   |      0        |      1        |
Timeout: No Response from 172.20.36.8
Timeout: No Response from 172.20.36.8
Timeout: No Response from 172.20.36.8
172.20.36.8     |       |               |      0        |
```

when it reaches the ip address `.6` and `.8`, it displays `"Timeout: No Response..."`. I wanted somehow to display it like this if it encounters no response from the said ip address:

```
172.20.36.3     |   1   |      2        |      4        |
172.20.36.4     |   2   |      5        |      8        |
172.20.36.5     |   3   |      11       |      16       |
172.20.36.6     |  Idle |     Idle      |     Idle      |
172.20.36.7     |   5   |      0        |      1        |
172.20.36.8     |  Idle |     Idle      |     Idle      |
```

can anyone out there that can help me to resolve this? I greatly appreciate your responses. :)

Comment: Why? It *isn't* idle. It has timed out trying to find out what the state actually is.

Comment: yes, it isn't idle literally, I just wanted to appear like that so that we know that the ip_address is not reachable.

Comment: Again, why? Why do you want to lie to your users? 'Idle' and 'unreachable' are different conditions. There are no prizes for conflation.

Comment: Sir I am not lying to the users, we are all technical support here who wants to have a functional script that we can use for our daily operation. All of us who will use the said script knows that if it displays "IDLE", that means that the certain ip address is not reachable. Do you have any suggestions then sir? can you help me at least a starting point to make a code rather than criticize what I am trying to do?

Comment: I am not lying to the users, this is the term we used in our company to identify which IP Addresses are unreachable, I think we should not interrogate nor criticize what the members here are trying to do, I am  making an effort to make a certain script to help our company not to lie to the company. I hope you get my point Sir EJP. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
SectorID=`$SNMPWALK -v2c -c Canopy ${EACH} ${SNMPOID}.1.1.16 2>&1 | sed 's/Timeout: No Response.*/Idle/'`
if [ "$SectorId" != "Idle" ] ; then
    SectorID=`echo $SectorID | awk '{ print $4 }'`
fi
```

But, the complexity of that script is growing rapidly and I'd be much more tempted to rewrite it in a better scripting environment than sh (I'm not bashing bash; I use it all the time) like python or perl.  But if you want to use *sh, I'd at least implement a function to do the processing for you once rather than repeating the above 4 times.  But I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Wes Hardaker. your script was very useful. The result is what I am expecting for. :)